# How can i create dynamic text and edit it using KineticJS. Any example to illustrate would be great

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I don't wish to use prompt for user input. Instead i wish to create
 interface such as in mspaint for creating or editing text.
 Below is the code i am using for creating text as of now, which takes user input through 
 javascript prompt.

```
text = function () {

            var mousePos,
                x,
                y,
                inputText;


            ui.stage.on('mousedown', function () {
                onMousedown();
            });


            function onMousedown(event) {

                mousePos = ui.stage.getPointerPosition();
                x = Math.floor(mousePos.x / ui.scale - ui.stage.getAbsolutePosition().x / ui.scale + ui.stage.getOffset().x);
                y = Math.floor(mousePos.y / ui.scale - ui.stage.getAbsolutePosition().y / ui.scale + ui.stage.getOffset().y);

                inputText = prompt('Enter a text');

                if ($.trim(inputText).length === 0) {
                    console.log('input text is empty');
                    return;
                }
                console.log(inputText);
                text = new drc.ui.Shape.Text({
                    x: x,
                    y: y,
                    fontSize: 30,
                    text: inputText,
                    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
                    fill: 'green'
                });

                ui.mainLayer.add(text);
                ui.mainLayer.draw();

            }
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

I've also made an attempt to create a from scratch solution editing directly on canvas using kineticJS.

I know it's reinventing the wheel, but when you have time to spare, why not? :)

It's actually most of the points markE has mentioned, implemented. Have a look at:

https://github.com/nktsitas/kineticjs-editable-text

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for document keystrokes on keypress and keydown.

```
// handle "printable" keys by listening for keypress

$(document).on('keypress',(function(e){ ...  }));

// handle control keys like backspace by listening for keydown

$(document).on('keydown',(function(e){ ... }));
```

Then add each printable key to your Kinetic.Text object as it's stroked.

You can also remove the last character when the backspace is stroked.

Here is example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    // this variable holds the current text
    var typedText="";

    // create a text object
    var text = new Kinetic.Text({
        x: 20,
        y: 30,
        fontSize: 30,
        text: "",
        fontFamily: 'Calibri',
        fill: 'green'
    });
    layer.add(text);
    layer.draw();


    // listen for keys

    // get the usual "printable" keys
    $(document).on('keypress',(function(e){

        // get the key
        key=e.which;

        // let keydown handle control keys 
        if(key<32){return;}

        // add the typed character
        typedText+=String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
        text.setText(typedText);;
        layer.drawScene();
    }));


    // handle control keys like backspace
    $(document).on('keydown',(function(e){

        // get the key
        var key=event.which;

        // Let keypress handle displayable characters
        if(key>46){ return; }


        // handle the backspace 
        // (and any other control keys you want to program)
        switch(key){
              case 8: //backspace:
                if(typedText.length>0){
                    typedText=typedText.slice(0,-1);
                    text.setText(typedText);;
                    layer.drawScene();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }));


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>
<body>
    <p>Type...(and use the backspace)!</p>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

*[ Here’s an outline of how to add a basic text editor to html canvas ]*

While this works (I have it in several projects), I would instead recommend floating an html textarea over canvas when you need a basic text editor.

So...against my better judgement, here's how to turn canvas into a text editor...

**Define some text related variables:**

- theText (string): the current text,
- tabLength (number):  the # of spaces in a tab,
- cursorIndex (number): the cursor’s character position withing theText,

**Listen for the user’s “printable” keystrokes in the keypress handler:**

- Event.which has the numeric keycode
- If Event.which >= 32, the key is printable, so add it to theText
- If a character has been added to theText, advance cursorIndex++

**Listen for the user’s command keystrokes in keydown and respond accordingly:**

- Backspace: remove last character in theText,
- Tab: append spaces*tabLength to theText,
- End: cursorIndex=theText.length,
- Home: cursorIndex=0,
- Left: cursorIndex--,
- Right: cursorIndex++,
- Delete: remove character at cursorIndex

**Managing the cursor:**

- Use context.measureText to get the XY at cursorIndex within theText,
- Advance the cursorIndex in response to user’s typing of printable characters,
- Reposition the cursorIndex in response to user's typing of command keys,
- Draw the blinking cursor at cursorIndex using requestAnimationFrame,

Comment: Thanks much. Code is working fine. 
Please guide on how to make text display as edit mode once you add it into canvas or when you try to edit text after double click. Also, how can we edit text by moving cursor keys after text is selected.

Comment: I added an outline of how to do text editing using html canvas to my answer.  However...My Strong Suggestion: Instead of implimenting a text editor in canvas, just float an html textarea over canvas when you need user text input.

Comment: hi markE, thank you so much for the outline. I hope you must have implemented this feature in your project. Could you please share the code snippet, so that i could move on from there.

Comment: I coded a basic text editor for canvas a while back and I can dig out that code.  However, **I strongly suggest not reinventing the wheel and instead just float an html textarea over the canvas to get user text input.**  That is a much better tool for text input...

Comment: do you have any code snippet to share for above outline, without the use of text area.

Comment: It wasn't a snippet--more like 400+ lines. Again, just float an html textarea to get user input. It's the best tool for the job because that's what the textarea was designed to do.  You can restyle the textarea by removing its border and its background color.  You’re quickly left with the same thing that 400 lines of canvas-js achieves. Cheers!

Comment: @markE - I tried following you advice to hover a text area but I can't figure out how to position it correctly - it shows with offset: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945018/positioning-textarea-over-canvas-text